# Android Mediaplayer :: How to detect streaming content type (audio or video)

Tags: android, media-player

I am completely new to displaying streaming either audio or video content using media player.

Somehow using post available here, i am able to display RTSP content(.3gp video) in my MediaPlayer implementation.

How to identify streaming content is audio only stream or audio/video stream using MediaPlayer class or streaming link?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong here, but I believe there is only a `MediaPLayer.OnInfoListner` API available in Java to get information about the content stream being played. Not sure of how helpful that API actually is though. You might also want to try stream scrapers(is what I believe they are called) to get stream data and see if there is both audio and video channel to make a determination.

Comment: Thanks, Any other suggestions !!